# Perl share variables with subclasses

Tags: perl

I know this may be a very simple topic but I am trying to get the best logic since I am still new to Perl.

If I do not use OO and just split the code into files, all global variables are accessed among all files.

I am trying to do the same but using OO style. Example is I want a base class say called "BaseSub" that has a hash containing the configuration for the application say called %Config. Now I have a sub class called "DB" for the database connection and I want to access the settings from %Config which lives in "BaseSub" package. How do I do that.

Comment: Do you have any code that you are currently working in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing OO perl in this day and age, you really should be using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose). It makes OO code much easier, cleaner and smaller.

The proper way to inherit variables is to make object attributes. Here's a quick example:

```
package MyBaseClass;

use Moose; 

has config => (
    is => 'ro',
    default => sub { {
        who => 'World',
    } }
);

package MyClass;

use Moose;

extends qw(MyBaseClass);

sub greet
{
    my $self = shift;
    printf("Hello %s!\n", $self->config->{who});
}

package main;

my $object = MyClass->new();

$object->greet();
```

A great starting point for learning about Moose is the [Moose::Manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual).

**Edit:**

If you want be able to modify the config, you can either just poke the hashref returned from the config accessor directly:

```
$object->config->{who} = 'Friends';
```

But a better approach might be to make a config class and make the config attribute hold an instance of that:

```
package Myconfig;

use Moose;

has who => (is => 'rw', default => 'World');

package MyBaseClass;

use Moose;

has config => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'MyConfig',
    default => sub { MyConfig->new },
);

# inherit, instantiate, etc as before...

$object->config->who('Friends');
```

Another approach could be [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Hash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aAttribute%3a%3aNative%3a%3aTrait%3a%3aHash) which makes it easy to setup helper methods to work with native Perl datatypes.

Comment: Good, how can I make the config attr a dynamic hash also as a dynamic array that I can change from the base class or even sub class.

Comment: Updated my answer to include suggestions for making a modifiable config attribute.

Comment: Is Moose installed on hosting domains by default since it is none standard Perl module or will I have to ask them to install it on the server?

Answer (score 3):

Use its full name.

```
for (keys(%BaseSub::Config)) {
    print("$_: $BaseSub::Config{$_}\n");
}
```

You could also import it.

```
our %Config; *Config = \%BaseSub::Config;

for (keys(%Config)) {
    print("$_: $Config{$_}\n");
}
```

Comment: `for (keys %Config)`?